# How do I load an XML doc into Excel using the Open XML SDK and .Net

Tags: .net, wpf, excel, openxml

In a WPF desktop application, I need to create an Excel 2007/2010 on a production server without office installed.  I have a bunch of XML files which I want to load into separate pages of the workbook, mimicking the 'Data>Get External Data>From XML Import' operation, and resulting in something like:

[image: The Excel worksheet]

I think my best bet would be the Open XML SDK, but am not sure this is possible.

Comment: is this a web application or a winforms application..?

Comment: Edited - WPF desktop application

Comment: if xml files are always the same, and accessible by the user, you can create a standard excel file with data connection instead of generating the whole Excel file. Far more easier to build, if you have your datasource always accessible. The ds can be xml file, web service (I like WCF Rest for that), etc.

Comment: No, there are about 50 types of XML files.  Excel is great in just importing them, and I would like to replicate this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (horrible name) for doing high-level Excel file manipulation through the OpenXML standard.  It abstracts out a lot of the complexity of dealing directly with the OpenXML interfaces.

Tiny example:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World!";
workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
```

Comment: Will Look at this. Do you know of similar library for Word?

Comment: Nope, no love from the Internets on OpenXML for Word.  Also, I just found EPPlus (http://epplus.codeplex.com/), which is an analagous library for modifying Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Templater](http://templater.info). Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.

The code would look something like this:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("test1.xml");
dataSet.ReadXml("test2.xml");
using (var doc = Configuration.Factory.Open("test.xlsx"))
    doc.Process(dataSet);
Process.Start("test.xlsx");
```

Comment: This looks interesting.  I will give it a spin!